# How can I prettify my compiled binary of FFmpeg?

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg, compilation, cross-compiling, compiler-optimization

After many weeks and a *lot* of effort, I finally managed to use a Cygwin and MinGW-w64 toolchain to cross-compile a working binary of FFmpeg for Windows, complete with the superior but elusive *fdk_aac* encoder.

However, comparing my newly-compiled binary with the official pre-compiled build for Windows makes me feel a little... lacking (first run is the Zeranoe build, second is my own):

[image]

Notice how the Zeranoe build's banner is missing all of the unseemly-looking configure options apart from the external libraries. Along with that, it also has the date that the program was built on inserted right after the GCC version.

How were the compilers of this build able to add these enhancements to their binary, and how can I do the same? I'm assuming these are simply GCC or preprocessor options that I can't find any information on, or maybe there's more to it than that.

*N.B: I'm aware of the `--no-banner` switch for FFmpeg, and that's not what I'm trying to do here.*

Comment: Zeranoe's builds are not officially from the FFmpeg project. Anyway, there is a forum on Zeranoe's site. Maybe you can ask him directly.

Comment: @llogan I'm aware, I created a thread there over 3 weeks ago when I was having compilation issues, and a second a week ago, and either of them have still yet to be approved yet alone answered, so I don't have much confidence in that forum. I might try the mailing lists, which were downright terrible for help purposes but might be willing to give me the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't GCC options, they are direct changes made to the source.

You can manually edit what is displayed on the banner in the `cmdutils.c` file in the FFmpeg source - in the function `print_program_info`, lines 1145 to 1157:

```
static void print_program_info(int flags, int level)
{
    const char *indent = flags & INDENT? "  " : "";

    av_log(NULL, level, "%s version " FFMPEG_VERSION, program_name);
    if (flags & SHOW_COPYRIGHT)
        av_log(NULL, level, " Copyright (c) %d-%d the FFmpeg developers",
               program_birth_year, CONFIG_THIS_YEAR);
    av_log(NULL, level, "\n");
    av_log(NULL, level, "%sbuilt with %s\n", indent, CC_IDENT);

    av_log(NULL, level, "%sconfiguration: " FFMPEG_CONFIGURATION "\n", indent);
}
```

There, you can manually add to the function things like the current date, etc or remove things entirely.